# Get http status in Qt WebKit

Tags: http, qt, webkit, webview, status

What I would like to implement is

## 1 Using Qt's WebView(part of QtWebKit) to access some page.

## 2 Show specified html page if got HTTP 4xx, 5xx status

(Ex> HTTP 404, 500).

## 3 Also shows specified page when network connection is unavailable.

For now, I had only done job 1...
In job 2, how did I get http status from WebView ?
In job 3, I'm looking about QUrl APIs now.

Anyone have idea or expreience yet ?

Answer (score 0):

You should reimplement QWebPage::extension() with extension type of QWebPage::ErrorPageExtension.

For details see:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebpage.html#extension, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebpage-errorpageextensionoption.html

Comment: Very thanks for your help. Due to time issue, I had use a VERY STUPID way to done it...:(
My boss did something that I totally can't accept, so I just quit, and maybe not to programming in Qt for a long time...